# Does Alljoyn support iOS

Tags: ios, alljoyn

Does Alljoyn really support iOS?  It seems the last release supports iOS 8.x.  Have not seen anything beyond 8.x.  Am I missing something?  Looking for a way to use interoperable WiFi Peer-to-Peer on Android, iOS, and Windows10 (Mobile) platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AllJoyn supports iOS. [This](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx) library was written on Objective-C and company I worked at had to support and upgrade the framework by our own. The code is private.

You could also [ask](https://ask.allseenalliance.org) and [learn](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/tutorial/ios) something on their official page.

**UPD:**

- AllJoyn is connecting with [Open Connectivity Foundation](https://openconnectivity.org/announcements/allseen-alliance-merges-open-connectivity-foundation-accelerate-internet-things). So better to look at [their](https://openconnectivity.org/developer) solution.
- And look at this [IoTivity](https://www.iotivity.org) solution. Seems promising.

Comment: The last release was for iOS 8.x.  Will the Objective-C libraries still run on iOS 10 and soon to be iOS 11?  What kind of performance did you get in terms of MBytes/sec.  Any long latency issues?  What is the connection type -- P2P, WiFi infrastructure, roll-your-own WiFi P2P?  Thanks for your service on this project.

Comment: Long appliance discovering (3 sec minimum). WiFi infrastructure in one WiFi local network.

Comment: I looked through OCF and ioTivity.  A couple of observations.  I don't want to paintbrush the who initiative but, the main focus of OCF seems to be Internet of Things.  Mobile P2P appears to be a secondary focus.  There does not appear to be an interoperable P2P solution available at this time.  Looks like most of the P2P focus is Android.  I can't find any recent iOS support with AllJoyn or IoTivity.  AllJoyn has been folded into IoTivity.  Does anyone know of an interoperable mobile P2P solution?